# Multiplying two elements in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

How can I multiply two elements in a list?
I am reading a text file, and printing the following:

```
for i in range(len(listeisotoper)):
    print("Isotop type:"+listeisotoper[i][0])
    print("Isotopisk masse u: "+listeisotoper[i][1])
    print("Naturlig forekomst: "+listeisotoper[i][2])
    print("xxx"+"g/mol")
    print("\n")
```

However i cannot fathom how i can multiply the `listeisotoper[i][1] * listeisotoper[i][2]`
and then have it print the number with decimal points.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Why can't you do `listeisotoper[i][1]*listeisotoper[i][2]`?

Comment: It's unclear what's wrong with using`listeisotoper[i][1]*listeisotoper[i][2]` as you suggested. Also, please fix your code's indentation.

Comment: "**reading a text file**", then you need to convert string value to float

Comment: Get out of the habit of using `for index in range(len(list)):`. Use `for item in list:` or `for index, item in enumerate(list):`

Comment: @Barmar And in this case we don't even need the index.

Comment: @Matthias It's a canned comment, so I give the `enumerate` suggestion for when it's needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't clear question for me, but may be this code will help you

```
for i in range(len(listeisotoper)):
    print("Isotop type:"+listeisotoper[i][0])
    print("Isotopisk masse u: "+listeisotoper[i][1])
    print("Naturlig forekomst: "+listeisotoper[i][2])
    mult_res = float(listeisotoper[i][1]) * float(listeisotoper[i][2]) 
    print(f"Mult = {mult_res:.1f}")
    print("xxx"+"g/mol")
    print("\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your problem is multiplying strings. If so, try this:

```
for i in range(len(listeisotoper)):
    print("Isotop type:"+listeisotoper[i][0])
    print("Isotopisk masse u: "+listeisotoper[i][1])
    print("Naturlig forekomst: "+listeisotoper[i][2])
    print(str(float(listeisotoper[i][1])*float(listeisotoper[i][2]))+"g/mol")
    print("\n")
```

Comment: He mentioned decimal points, so it should be `float()` rather than `int()`

Comment: No, it's a list. but i found a workaround, not pretty but it does the job done, now i just have to figure out how to print it with that text :)

  x= float(listeisotoper[i][1])
  x1=float(listeisotoper[i][2])

Comment: Beside the point, but that's really hard to read. It'd be better to calculate in one line then print it in another. And use an f-string. `res = int(listeisotoper[i][1]) * int(listeisotoper[i][2])); print(f"{res}g/mol")`